# Is @Ref of spring-data-reference (arangodb) uses eager or lazy fetching of the referenced object?

Tags: spring, arangodb, ref

I'm writing a schema which includes some referenced objects. I'm trying to understand whether the actual fetching of the referenced object is lazy or eager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `arangodb-spring-data 3.2.5` the default fetch of referenced objects should be eager, as you can see in the `@Ref` annotation class.

> Ref.class

```
package com.arangodb.springframework.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Reference;

/**
 * Annotation to indicate that the annotated field is stored as a document in
 * another collection instead of a nested document. The document {@literal _id}
 * of that document is stored as a reference in the stored field.
 *
 * @author Mark Vollmary
 *
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Reference
public @interface Ref {

    /**
     * Whether the entity should be loaded lazily
     */
    boolean lazy() default false;

}
```

To make the referenced data loading lazy you should annotate it with

```
@Ref(lazy = true)
```